# How to dynamically insert a keyword in an Amazon Search Widget

Tags: amazon, widgets

Through Amazon Associates, you can create search widgets that have a place for a search term.  In the admin, you can set the default search term, but that seems to be tied to the widget ID.

I would like to be able to dynamically set the search term for the widget when it is displayed.

How can I accomplish this?

**Note:**

I am referring to the following banner script:

```
<SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_sw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%2F[PARTNER-ID]%2F8002%2F84cb1754-d9ab-48de-b96b-574927fa9599"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A HREF="http://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_sw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%2F[PARTNER-ID]%2F8002%2F84cb1754-d9ab-48de-b96b-574927fa9599&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.ca Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
```

Comment: Here's a JavaScript snippet that you can adapt for you need -http://mvark.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-display-book-titles-in-amazon.html

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the search term dynamically with the [Recommended Product Links widget](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/build-links/dynamic/main.html)

When I use it I get code formatted like this (amazon affiliate id removed):

```
<iframe src="http://rcm-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?t=affiliateid&o=1&p=6&l=st1&mode=apparel&search=stripes&fc1=000000&lt1=_blank&lc1=3366FF&bg1=FFFFFF&f=ifr" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="120" height="150" border="0" frameborder="0" style="border:none;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

it has the parameter `search=stripes` in it.  "stripes" was the search term that I typed in to create the widget when selecting the category "women's appearal".  You should be able to replace that parameter to modify this widget.